# How do 用不起 / 用得起 and 吃不起 / 吃得起 mean (un)affordable?

Tags: meaning, complement

Among [potential complements](https://resources.allsetlearning.com/chinese/grammar/Potential_complement) are [some ending with 得起](https://resources.allsetlearning.com/chinese/grammar/Advanced_potential_complements#Verbs_with_-.E4.B8.8D.E8.B5.B7_and_-.E5.BE.97.E8.B5.B7).  Some examples (from [here](https://resources.allsetlearning.com/chinese/grammar/Advanced_potential_complements#Verbs_with_-.E4.B8.8D.E8.B5.B7_and_-.E5.BE.97.E8.B5.B7) and [here](https://www.lingolearn.com/learn-languages/learn-chinese/chinese-words-for-unable-to-and-able-to-%E4%B8%8D%E8%B5%B7buqi-and-%E5%BE%97%E8%B5%B7deqi/)) are:

> 这家餐厅太贵了，我们**吃不起**。
> This restaurant is too expensive. We **can't afford** to eat here.
>
> 我们**吃得起**龙虾。
> We **can afford** lobster.

> 这些化妆品很贵，我**用不起**。
> This makeup is very expensive. I **can't afford** it.
>
> 我们**用得起**电。
> We **can afford** electricity.

The Chinese Zero To Hero YouTube video [动词+得/不+起](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ogsqRcpQeIU) gives an idea of the conversion: basically, 不能[verb] = [verb]不起 and 能[verb] = [verb]得起.  But then 吃不起 should mean 不能吃 = "I can't eat [something]" and 吃得起 should mean 能吃 = "I can eat [something]" (and likewise for 用).  So I'm not following the logic here.

**Question**: How do 用不起 / 用得起 and 吃不起 / 吃得起 mean (un)affordable?

Comment: Although both 不能 and  不起 are negative, they are not equivalent. 不能 is cannot; 不起 is, as you have pointed out, cannot afford. Cannot is not the same as cannot afford.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In China, we more of use this as a fixed phrase for (cannot) afford. For example, we would use 吃不起 or 用不起 or 买不起 to show that we cannot afford to eat/use/buy something. The simple logic is this:

-得起 means that you can afford to do an action

-不起 means that you cannot afford to do an action

This is probably a fixed phrase you need to memorize.

P.S. When we use -得起 or -不起, we do not necessarily mean afford in the monetary context. For example, we can say 我承担不起这个后果 to mean "I cannot bear (承担) this consequence (后果)".

Answer (score 0):

`得起` and `不起` is part of common expression in Chinese for can/cannot afford.

If you broke characters, `起` generally means to support, to lift. So the express literally translates into you are able to support(lift)/ you cannot support(lift).